# A query with MIN(date) not finished in 20 hours: should it be like that, or I did something wrong?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, query-performance

Inspired with [a post by Tommaso Pifferi](https://medium.com/@neslinesli93/how-to-efficiently-store-and-query-time-series-data-90313ff0ec20), I've created a PostgreSQL (11) database to operate on my time series data: 316K financial instruments, 139M records in total. Time series of different instruments vary in length and time periods, and often have gaps. There are two tables: description of instruments and data of time series records. The structure is very simple:

- `TABLE instruments` has

  - `instr_id INT PRIMARY KEY` and
  - 9 more columns describing each instrument,
- `TABLE timeseries` has

  - `PRIMARY KEY (instr_id, date)` where
  - `instr_id INT REFERENCES instruments(instr_id)` connects time series records with instrument description,
  - `date DATE NOT NULL` is the date of time series records

    There is no index on `date`.
  - 5 more columns containing indicators such as price, trading volume, etc.

I work in Python 3.7, use psycopg2 as the driver and sqlalchemy as the ORM (but this is probably irrelevant). First I filled in the database using DataFrame.to_sql, ran VACUUM and checked that simple queries work correctly. Then I wanted to add to the table `instruments` some columns summarizing time series properties. Here is the first query I ran using `cursor.execute()` in order to test this idea. It supposed to find for each time series, what is the date of the earliest time record:

```
ALTER TABLE instruments
    ADD begin DATE; 
UPDATE instruments SET
    begin = (
        SELECT MIN(date) FROM timeseries
        WHERE timeseries.instr_id=instruments.instr_id
            );
```

This query has been running on a desktop PC (Intel i5, 8GB memory, Windows 7) for about 20 hours with no result. The server activity displayed in pgAdmin 4 looks as below.

I am new to relational databases and SQL. Is it normal that such a query performs so long, or do I do anything wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Updates like that are typically faster if you aggregate once over everything and join that into the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE instruments 
  SET "begin" = t.start_date
FROM (
  SELECT instr_id, MIN(date) 
  FROM timeseries
  group by instr_id
) t
WHERE t.instr_id = instruments.instr_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much @a_horse_with_no_name, @michał-zaborowski, @laurenz-albe for your help and quick response. First I executed 'CREATE INDEX ON timeseries (date);' as proposed by @laurenz-albe; it took minutes. Then I executed the query with a temporary table as proposed by @a_horse_with_no_name with the following corrections: remove quotes around `begin`, add `AS start_date` after `MIN(date)`. The query took 3 m 11 s to complete. In order to check what is the contribution of reformulating the query, I also ran the query in the initial form. It started around an hour ago and is still running.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by a_horse_with_no_name is the correct one, but if you want to speed up the query without rewriting it, you should

```
CREATE INDEX ON timeseries (date);
```

That would speed up the repeated subselect and hence the whole query considerably.

Answer (score 2):

What has to be done to get `MIN(date)`? Well - whole table of 139M records has to be scanned... For every instrument - and that is explanation.

To see how query is executed, please, use `explain` - [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) you can find documentation. Note that using `explain analyze` can take that 5 hours since query has to be executed in order to collect all the information.

What to do? You can create index. Question is if that would work. PG will use index if query fetches less then 2% of the table. In other cases it will go with `seqscan` - read of whole table. If you feel that `seqscan` is your case you can consider adding date to the index - that way, instead of reading the table DB can use stats of that index. To check - use explain.

That is general answer. Just try to play with it. If you have more questions, we can try to build up final answer.